# Spring Boot maps request to Controller and ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, controller

My Controller, that should, for now at least, simply return all users known to Hibernate, is not executed, despite being mapped to by spring boot. Instead the request is then mapped to the ResourceHttpRequestHandler. It still returns StatusCode 200.

The Controller in question:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = Path.ROOT+"/users")

public class UserController {

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

@Autowired
private IUserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers(){
    log.info("Users: "+userRepository.findAll().size());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userRepository.findAll());
}

}
```

Here the Log output:

```
2019-12-04 16:34:34.615 DEBUG 17008 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.app.controllers.users.UserController#getAllUsers()
2019-12-04 16:34:34.618 DEBUG 17008 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2019-12-04 16:34:34.620  INFO 17008 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.app.security.JWT.JwtRequestFilter  : Do Filter Internal
2019-12-04 16:34:34.620  INFO 17008 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.app.security.JWT.JwtRequestFilter  : Should filter
```

As you can see, the log output from the getAllUsers-Method is not there.
I can also confirm that the JwtRequestFilter is not messing with the request directly, as the response code is 200, and there is no message.

EDIT:
I have nailed down the Problem to Spring Security. If the security is disabled for the request, it is properly executed. 
More specifically, if the shouldNotFilter in my custom OncePerRequestFilter returns true, this error occurs. However, even if the actual filter-method merely contains `return` this error still occurs.

Comment: could you share the URL you are sending the request to? do you have the ending / in the URL?

Comment: @SaimDoruklu http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/
I should perhaps add that another controller does map correctly, although it is excluded from security.

Comment: @TerpeTubebaker you should append `/` in URL as part of the mapping path you have specified for `getAllUsres()`

Comment: I have tried both, with / and without. The URL i posted is actually with a trailing /, but stackoverflow formatting ommits it.

Comment: I have found some interesting interactions however:
In my Model classes, there are Collections with a xtoMany Relationship. If their fetchType is set to LAZY, i will get a LazyInitializationException, which to me would indicate an execution of the method. however, log output does not represent that fact.